# Python Function to return a list of common letters in first and last names

Tags: python, list

Question: DO NOT USE SETS IN YOUR FUNCTION: Uses lists to return a list of the common letters in the first and last names (the intersection) Prompt user for first and last name and call the function with the first and last names as arguments and print the returned list.

I can't figure out why my program is just printing "No matches" even if there are letter matches. Anything helps! Thanks a bunch!

Code so far:

```
import string

def getCommonLetters(text1, text2):
""" Take two strings and return a list of letters common to
    both strings."""
    text1List = text1.split()
    text2List = text2.split()
    for i in range(0, len(text1List)):
        text1List[i] = getCleanText(text1List[i])
    for i in range(0, len(text2List)):
        text2List[i] = getCleanText(text2List[i])

    outList = []
    for letter in text1List:
        if letter in text2List and letter not in outList:
           outList.append(letter)
    return outList

def getCleanText(text):
"""Return letter in lower case stripped of whitespace and
punctuation characters"""
    text = text.lower()

    badCharacters = string.whitespace + string.punctuation
    for character in badCharacters:
        text = text.replace(character, "")
    return text

userText1  = raw_input("Enter your first name: ")
userText2  = raw_input("Enter your last name: ")
result     = getCommonLetters(userText1, userText2)
numMatches = len(result)
if numMatches == 0:
    print "No matches."
else:
    print "Number of matches:", numMatches

for letter in result:
    print letter
```

Comment: The problem seems to be you writing Java with Python syntax...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
def CommonLetters(s1, s2):
    l1=list(''.join(s1.split()))
    l2=list(''.join(s2.split()))
    return [x for x in l1 if x in l2]

print CommonLetters('Tom','Dom de Tommaso')
```

Output:

```
>>> ['T', 'o', 'm']
```

Comment: thank you SO MUCH! That literally just saved me. I've been working on this problem for hours.

Comment: There is no need to convert the strings to lists. Strings are already iterable. I would even skip splitting since that doesn't remove punctuation so you still need a separate filtering step. Just `def common_letters(s1, s2): return [x for x in s1 if x in s2]` does the trick.

Comment: @JBernardo No `set`s was specified in the question.

Comment: @agf ops, I skipped the first line of the question :)

Comment: The solution does not work at all, plus it is a homework. You don't do students' homework, or at least you give good solutions.

Comment: @VincentSavard what do you mean it doesn't work? Your answer did help. . .?

Comment: @user1210588: The solution given by carrot-top does not work. Try `CommonLetters('Matteo', 'Dom de Tommaso')` for instance, you'll see for yourself easily. Try putting both strings in lowercase also. He just picked a solution that happened to give the good results, nonetheless it's still bad.

Comment: I see what you mean about the lower and upper cases not matching. Where in my code should I address this issue (disregarding this solution) ?

Comment: @Vincent Savard: It is not apparent that `M` and `m` should match in CommonLetters(). If so, using `s1.upper()` would fix that.

Comment: @user1210588: It's not only about lower/uppercases. If `l1` contains the same letter more than once, it will be listed more than once too.

Comment: @Vincent Savard: It is also not clear from the description that multiple entries in the list is *wrong* per se. If so, it is easily fixed by using a dictionary key rather than a list.

Answer (score 3):

```
for letter in text1List:
```

Here's your problem. text1List is a *list*, not a *string*. You iterate on a list of strings (['Bobby', 'Tables'] for instance) and you check if 'Bobby' is in the list text2List.

You want to iterate on every character of your string text1 and check if it is present in the string text2.

There's a few non-pythonic idioms in your code, but you'll learn that in time.

Follow-up: What happens if I type my first name in lowercase and my last name in uppercase? Will your code find any match?

Answer (score 1):

Prior to `set()` being the common idiom for duplicate removal in Python 2.5, you could use the conversion of a list to a dictionary to remove duplicates.

Here is an example:

```
def CommonLetters(s1, s2):
    d={}
    for l in s1:
        if l in s2 and l.isalpha():
            d[l]=d.get(l,0)+1
    return d                             

print CommonLetters('matteo', 'dom de tommaso')
```

This prints the count of the common letters like so:

```
{'a': 1, 'e': 1, 'm': 1, 't': 2, 'o': 1}
```

If you want to have a list of those common letters, just use the keys() method of the dictionary:

```
print CommonLetters('matteo', 'dom de tommaso').keys()
```

Which prints just the keys:

```
['a', 'e', 'm', 't', 'o']
```

If you want upper and lower case letters to match, add the logic to this line:

```
if l in s2 and l.isalpha():
```