# Similar Character's in two strings, return all similar characters (no repetitive characters) problemsetquestion in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

In advance, I have searched for a solution to this problem already but there does not seem to be one in existence. So I am currently trying to self teach python by running through the Python "Path" on http://singpath.appspot.com and I ran into a problem I do not understand how to solve. I have tried multiple different ways to solve it but keep coming up with different incorrect results. Any hints/help would be spectacular! Thanks in advance!

Question:

> #### Comparing Strings
>
> Create a function that takes an input of two strings
> and returns a string that contains all of the characters that appear
> in both of the inputs. The result should not have any repeats and
> should be listed in sorted order.    You might want to use the
> variable lowercase from the string module so that you have all the
> letters in order.

My Current Code:

```
def in_both(s1, s2):
    s1 = s1.lower()
    s2 = s2.lower()
    
    l1=list(''.join(s1.split()))
    l2=list(''.join(s2.split()))
    
    same = ''
    
    for i in l1:
        if i in l2:
            
            same = ''.join(i)
    
    return same
```

Example:

```
call: in_both('apple','orange') recieved: 'e' expected: 'ae'
```

As you can see it is only collecting a single similar character. Any suggestions? I've tried a couple of different things but I am unsure where to go from here! Please help!

P.s. I got the list idea from a similar question located here: [Python Function to return a list of common letters in first and last names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742832/python-function-to-return-a-list-of-common-letters-in-first-and-last-names)

I understand how it works the problem is I have to return a string with all comparisons at the same time. Thanks 'the wolf' for the idea for the list(s) of characters.

Comment: Not sure what you're going for with `''.join(s2.split())`. Removing spaces doesn't seem to be in the question

Comment: And you have to use something like that? You can't just do `''.join(sorted(set(string1).intersection(string2)))` ? (minus any casing issues)

Comment: @JonClements As I stated "I got the list idea from a similar question located here: Python Function to return a list of common letters in first and last names" I'm still new to programming but I understood that code to know it worked to make the list to work. Thanks for pointing out this new and more simplistic method of doing things it. The more I learn the better!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get unique characters in any string by turning it into a set.
The you can get the intersection of two sets using `intersection`.
And you can sort the result, which returns a list.

```
def in_both(s1, s2):
    s1 = s1.lower()
    s2 = s2.lower()
    s1_chars = set(s1)
    s2_chars = set(s2)
    result = sorted(s1_chars.intersection(s2_chars))
    return result
```

Comment: That code is way cleaner than mine :P I guess I better look into set() sooner than later. Thanks for your solution! P.s. The one problem is it's supposed to return a string but that can easily be overcome with ''.join(string) right?

Comment: Note that `set.intersection` takes an iterable so it's not necessary for `s2_chars` to be a set.

Comment: @Steve K Great XD Thanks for introducing me to set()!

Comment: @Jon Clements I really do need to learn set() :) Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 2):

You don't append to the variable "send" on each loop, you set it from scratch. I suppose you want to change the line

```
same = ''.join(i)
```

to:

```
same += i
```

Comment: Ahhhh I'm a dunce! Your right I must have forgotten the plus. However when I run it  with the '+=' it will add the same similar characters to the variable :P Nothing a quick if statement can't fix :) Thanks for pointing out my obvious (and embarassing) syntax error!

Comment: @Winkleson: You realize `''.join(i)`, where `i` is a string, is the same as `i`?

Comment: @Eric Of course your right. I just took his code and did'nt thought much about that part about it.

Comment: @Eric yeah I was playing around with the code alot that probably had to do with some type transfers from earlier and trying to solve some type errors with no positive result :P

Comment: @NiclasNilsson ok so now I need the result to be called in alphabetical order... any suggestions? Looking for built in modules atm. IE: Python Standard Library

Comment: @Winkleson Instead of append to a string, append to a list (it seems more natural in the first place). Then you can sort with "sorted(same)" and return it as a string with "''.join(same)

Answer (score 1):

You can convert into set of char first and then find intersection

```py
str1 = 'apple'
str2 = 'orange'
print list(str1)

set1 = set(list(str1))
set2 = set(list(str2))
setout = set1 & set2

print setout
myres = ''.join(setout)
print myres
```

Output of above code

kkiller-machine:Eclipse$ python unique.letter.py

```
['a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e']
set(['a', 'e'])
ae
```

Comment: Thanks for bringing up another way to solve it :P I have no practice with set() but I'm sure I'll learn to use it in the future!

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks everyone who helped me solve the question! The final solution I inputted is below. It may not be very pythonic but it get's the job done :) If I have any time later I'll come back and revisit the solution! Anyways thanks for your suggestions!

Code:

---

```
def in_both(s1, s2):
    s1 = s1.lower()
    s2 = s2.lower()

    l1=list(''.join(s1.split()))
    l2=list(''.join(s2.split()))

    same = []

    for i in l1:
        if i in l2:            
            if i not in same:
                same += i
                same = sorted(same)
                same = ''.join(same)

    return same
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
def in_both(s1,s2):
       l1 =[]
       l2 = []
       l1= list(s1.lower())
       l2= list(s2.lower())
       s = [i for i in l1 if i in l2]
       same = list(set(''.join(s)))
       return same
```

Comment: This would not have worked as it would have copies of the same similar characters (Say there are multiple same characters in both like 'poppy' and 'pineapple'. That's why I used multiple if's and one for loop in a non-Pythonic way of coding :P Thanks for your input though!

Comment: sorry Winkleson , was my mistake didn't read your question correct , you are right .i made some modulation for the one who is interesting in this code . thanks , and once again sorry for the inconvenient code .

Comment: No problem sir :) Any help is greatly appreciated and It's hard to deduct information from my run on sentences XD Thanks for your help!